# Dynamically translate Forms depending on local

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

So i'm making a multi-language site using symfony 2.8 but i had this problem when translating forms, i managed to change labels using translation_domain option like in this example:

```
->add('save','submit',
            array('label'=>'btn.send',
                'translation_domain' => 'FrontBundle',
                'attr'=>array(
                    'class'=>'btn btn-blue',
        )))
```

but i had a problem when translating entity type cause the names comes from the database so i added fields for other language
like this:

> name_fr ,name_en , name_es ,...

the problem was how to use them with the form, after hours of googling i found this solution even though I didn't like it.

using the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/form_dependencies.html) i passed the _local from request to my form like this:

contactController:

```
 public function contactAction(Request $request)
{
    $contact = new contact();
    $contact->setSendTime(new \DateTime('now'));
    $form = $this->createForm(new contactType(), $contact,array('lang'=>$request->getLocale()));
    //...
}
```

contactType:

```
class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    // ...

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        // ...

        $resolver->setRequired('lang');
    }
    //...
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $local = $options['lang'];
        // ...
        $builder

            ->add('civility', 'entity', array(
                'class'=>'BackBundle\Entity\civility',
                //use this
                'property' => $local == 'fr'?'name_fr':'name_en',
                //or this or dont use them both
                //'choice_label' => 'name',
                'label'=>'Civilité:',
                'expanded'=>true,
            ))
            /...
            ;

    }

}
```

i wonder if there is a less messier and better solution to translate the entity in forms

Comment: Have you tried [Translatable from the DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md)?

Comment: i'll read the documentation and give you a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i read [Translatable from the DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md) that @dbrumann give me and i use it side to side with [Sonata Translation Bundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataTranslationBundle) in the admin side and it works just fine.
if any one have any question about configuration put a comment

Answer (score 0):

you can use Symfony Form Events to dynamically manage form data. Check this out 
https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

It appears to be exactly what you need. You can pass the locale from your Controller to your Form (as an option) and within the Form class add an Event listener listening for an event (pick one that best suits your needs, my best guess is that you need the PRE_SET_DATA event - the one that manipulates the data from the database) and according to the passed locale option you can modify the form fields you need.